# Spring ROO error logs

Tags: spring-roo

When starting ROO for one of our projects I get this rather cryptic error message:

```
    ____  ____  ____
   / __ \/ __ \/ __ \
  / /_/ / / / / / / /
 / _, _/ /_/ / /_/ /
/_/ |_|\____/\____/    1.3.1.RELEASE [rev f4f5256]


Welcome to Spring Roo. For assistance press TAB or type "hint" then hit ENTER.
Method 'org.springframework.roo.classpath.details.MethodMetadataBuilder@4d896818[methodName=accept,parameterTypes=[]]' failed to provide a body, despite being identified for ITD inclusion
```

But without further hints it's hard to find out what's going on and what caused the error. Does ROO log somewhere more verbosely about what it does and, if so, where can I find ROO's log files?

The contents of log.roo are rather sparse, even after activating **development mode** - nothing regarding the error is logged while the same error message appears when roo is started. Also, no *.aj files are created or updated.

```
// Spring Roo 1.3.1.RELEASE [rev f4f5256] log closed at 2015-04-02 14:08:30
// Spring Roo 1.3.1.RELEASE [rev f4f5256] log opened at 2015-04-02 14:11:35
exit
// Spring Roo 1.3.1.RELEASE [rev f4f5256] log closed at 2015-04-02 16:21:40
// Spring Roo 1.3.1.RELEASE [rev f4f5256] log opened at 2015-04-02 16:23:49
development mode
exit
// Spring Roo 1.3.1.RELEASE [rev f4f5256] log closed at 2015-04-02 16:24:00
// Spring Roo 1.3.1.RELEASE [rev f4f5256] log opened at 2015-04-02 16:24:03
```

I would like to find out what type roo was processing when it ran into troubles and what can be done to resolve the issues. Are there any additional tools roo provides for error tracking and debugging?

Comment: Could you provide log.roo file to analyze your error? Could you create a JIRA ticket https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO with your issue? Regards,

Comment: @jcgarcia, thanks for getting involved! I've updated the post to provide the contents of log.roo which, alas, are rather sparse.

Comment: @jcgarcia To be able to provide an SSCCE we've created a multi-module spring project with entities implementing type hierarchies and project specific interfaces and made them active records, but were not able to reproduce the problem. So, we're pretty sure the original cause to the problem does not lie within ROO. But is there a way to get ROO to be more verbose in the log files so we can identify the location, probably within our sources, where ROO stumbles? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Having almost the same error: `Method 'org.springframework.roo.classpath.details.MethodMetadataBuilder@32752157[methodName=remove,parameterTypes=[]]' failed to provide a body, despite being identified for ITD inclusion` - were you able toresolve the issue?

Comment: @Manuel M alas, no. Not yet.